# Odoo 10 change field colour

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

I am trying to change the color of a field in Odoo10. here is my code

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/form//field[@name='analytic_tag_ids']" position="after">
                <label for="squarebox"/>
                <div>
                    <field name="squarebox"/>
                </div>
                <label for="squaremtrsold"/>
                <div>
                    <field name="squaremtrsold"/>
                </div>
            </xpath>
```

I tried `<field name="squarebox"style="background:Blue;"/>`

But this did not work?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the style for the div containing the field definition, since the field tag will not appear on the final html.

You could also add a class to the containing div and with some CSS rules you could target the field dom nodes to add the proper style rules

Answer (score 0):

Try this module https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/web_widget_color_field/

using above module widget you can change the filed colour as per your interest.

Answer (score 0):

You can give it a class, for instance 'squarebox', and then write your css code in your static folder, taking into account that your field will be rendered as an **input tag** later. So the next code should do the trick.

```
<label for="squarebox"/>
<div>
    <field name="squarebox" class="squarebox"/>
</div>
```

And then in your css file:

```
input.squarebox {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Pay attention to append your custom css to the assets, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<odoo>
    <template id="assets_backend" name="My Module Assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="//link[last()]" position="after">
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="your_module_name/static/src/css/styles.css"/>
        </xpath>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

And finally to the **manifest**.py

```
'data': [
    'views/your_custom_assets.xml',
    ],
'css': ['static/src/css/styles.css'],
```

You should upgrade your modulea, and if not working, enter in ?debug=assets mode